# SQL Server, foreach record in Table1 insert data in Table2 and Table3?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, loops

I wanted to know what should i use to iterate through data from

`temp Table1(15 columns + ID_autoinc)` and insert each record in real

```
Table2(10 colums + ID_autoinc) and real Table3(6 columns + ID_autoinc)?
```

Also while inserting data on Table2 i need the identity to insert it into Table3.

Conceptualy i need to:

```
SELECT * FROM  Table1 into #TempTable1

FOREACH-> Record in #TempTable1 {

INSERT INTO Table2(col1 ... col10) VALUES(#TempTable1.col1 ... #TempTable1.col10)
DECLARE @Table2Identity as int
@Table2Identity = SCOPE_IDENTITY()

INSERT INTO Table3(col1 ... col6) VALUES(@Table2Identity, #TempTable1.col11 ...   #TempTable1.col15)

}
```

Comment: what is the criteria to insert into each table from temp table ?
you can use merge.knowing sample data and criteria is important.

Comment: Don't loop. `insert into Table2 (col1, col2, col3) select col1, col2, col3 from table1`. Repeat for table3.

Comment: I updated my question, im still not sure if i explained it clearly. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please give us sample data (cut down the columns and rows to just enough to show us what you mean)

Comment: SQL is not made to iterate over data - you operate on sets.

Comment: it is lil clear but criteria still not clear.most probably merge will solve your problem or even output clause will solve it.on what basis you will insert into table1 from temp table only 10 rows ?

Comment: You can't insert into an identity column - is Table3's ID really an autoinc?

Answer (score 2):

```
MERGE Table2 AS target
using (select all column from table1  )) as source
on 0=1
WHEN NOT MATCHED then
INSERT (column name of table2 ) --table2
      VALUES (mention those column from source which need to insert int table2) --those
OUTPUT inserted.id,mention those column from source which need to insert int table1 INTO DetailsTable;
--inserted.id is that id of table2 that will be inserted in table2
```

try and ask

Answer (score 1):

Why do you need to iterate through Table1's data? You could just do INSERT statements on Table2 and Table3 with a SELECT from Table1, for example:

```
INSERT Table2(<Column1, Column2 etc)
SELECT Col1, Col2, etc from Table1;
```

and do the same for Table3.  You haven't mentioned what (if any) processing you want to do on the data from Table1 before inserting into Table2 and Table3

Answer (score 1):

You could declare a [cursor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180169.aspx) and loop through each row, but it's slow and more complex than it needs to be.

I don't think you actually need the temp table either.

If there's nothing in Table2 currently, then just do this:

```
insert into Table2 (col1, col2, ..)
select col1, col2, ..
from Table1

insert into Table3 (ID, col1, col2, ..)
select ID, col1, col2, ..
from Table2
```

Note that `Table3.ID` cannot be an `identity` column if you want to insert into it.

If Table2 already has some data, you should be able to do something like this:

```
begin transaction

declare @oldId int = select isnull(max(ID),0) from Table2

insert into Table2 (col1, col2, ..)
select col1, col2, ..
from Table1

insert into Table3 (ID, col1, col2, ..)
select ID, col1, col2, ..
from Table2
where ID > @oldID

commit
```